# Trying to connect to AWS Serverless

Tags: serverless

So I am trying to connect to AWS. For this I downloaded Serverless, serverless offline and Serverless MySQL. Once common thing on installation was something like

`added 82 packages from 531 contributors and audited 320 packages in 39.246s`

What exactly does this means.

Also I wanted to know when we are having packages in.json file there are some plugins that I still do not have. I know the manual process of downloading it one by one by naming, but wanted to know if there is a way to download all the remaining plugin at once instead of re-installing the environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to install a plugin

```
npm i --save-dev serverless-offline
```

`--save-dev` will register the plugin as a dependency in package.json

---

```
added 82 packages from 531 contributors and audited 320 packages in 39.246s
```

it mean

- 82 packages have been installed (dependencies and sub-dependencies)
- 531 people worked on it
- I don't know what's an audit but [it seems to be related to vulnerability](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/audit)
- 39.246s it the downloading time